# about Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions rule

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions rule

If I call a hook inside a regular function, and eventually call that function inside of a functional component, is it still against the rule above?

```js
export const getProducts = (
  searchParams: SearchParams) => {
  const result = useSearchProductsQuery({
    variables: {
      query: {
        projectId: projectId,
     
      }
    },
  });
  const data = result.data;

return data;
};


export const useGetProducts = (
  searchParams: SearchParams,
  dependencies: []
) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<{
    productsData: readonly any[]
    productsLoading: boolean;
  }>({
    productsData: [],
    productsLoading: false,
  });
  const productsResponse = getProducts(searchParams);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!productsResponse) return;
    setProducts(productsResponse);
  }, [productsResponse?.productsLoading, productsResponse?.productsData?.length, ...dependencies]);
  return { products, setProducts, getProducts };
};
```

and then `useGetProducts` is being used inside a functional component

Comment: @NicholasTower I just updated my question with a code, can you explain more what do you mean by middle of rendering?

Answer (score 2):

In the circumstances in which it won't throw an error, it'd be *possible*, but still a mistake, to an extent.

For it to not throw an error, the function would have to be called unconditionally - just like hooks have to be called conditionally. So

```
const Component = ({ bool }) => {
  if (bool) {
    someFnThatEventuallyCallsAHook();
  }
```

would be wrong, but

```
const Component = () => {
  someFnThatEventuallyCallsAHook();
```

could be permitted.

The hook must also be called before the function finishes returning. That is, given

```
const Component = () => {
  someFnThatEventuallyCallsAHook();
  // next line
```

The hook called in `someFnThatEventuallyCallsAHook` must be called before the interpreter gets to `// next line`.

For example:

```js
const x = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setVal(1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  console.log('val: ' + val);
};
const App = () => {
    x();
    return 'foo';
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

But this all is still usually a mistake. If you want to call a function inside a React component that calls a hook, you should make the function a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) instead, following the standard conventions - prefix the function with `use`. If a function's name doesn't start with `use`, it would be best not to call hooks inside it - even if doing so doesn't throw an error under some circumstances.

```
const Component = () => {
  someFnThatEventuallyCallsAHook();
```

looks pretty suspicious, but

```
const Component = () => {
  useSomeFnThatEventuallyCallsAHook();
```

is fine.

For the code you just edited into your question - your `useGetProducts` is a proper custom hook, so calling it at the top level of a component or inside another custom hook is fine. (Your `getProducts` function should be renamed to start with `use` so as to clearly communicate that it calls a hook inside.)

Comment: I just updated my question with the code I am using

Comment: and you think `useSearchProductsQuery` which is being called inside `getProducts` is also fine?

Comment: but getProducts is a regular function right ?

Comment: The `useGetProducts` function is fine, but the `getProducts` function isn't - since `getProducts` calls a hook, it should be renamed to start with `use`.